# Set Java compiler compliance level

Tags: java, javac, compiler-flags

I need to compile a Java program on the command line, and I am trying to set the compiler level to a lower one (1.6). I tried like this but it didn't work:

```
javac -1.6 Hello.java
```

Comment: I this the exact command what u are using? If not then please post the exact caommnds thats you are using.

Comment: Don't forget to add the `-bootclasspath` option to ensure that no 1.6 classes, methods or attributes are used in the code.

Comment: It worked like this: javac -target 1.6 -source 1.6 Hello.java

Comment: If I add -bootclasspath, where shoud bootclasspath indicate. I added the java install directory and I obtained the error "Fatal Error: Unable to find package java.lang in classpath or bootclasspath".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `-source` and `-target` options:

```
javac -target 1.6 -source 1.6 Hello.java
```

Answer (score 8):

Use: `javac -source 1.6 -target 1.6 Hello.java`

---

This information comes from running `javac -help`:

```
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
where possible options include:
  -g                         Generate all debugging info
  -g:none                    Generate no debugging info
  -g:{lines,vars,source}     Generate only some debugging info
  -nowarn                    Generate no warnings
  -verbose                   Output messages about what the compiler is doing
  -deprecation               Output source locations where deprecated APIs are used
  -classpath <path>          Specify where to find user class files and annotation processors
  -cp <path>                 Specify where to find user class files and annotation processors
  -sourcepath <path>         Specify where to find input source files
  -bootclasspath <path>      Override location of bootstrap class files
  -extdirs <dirs>            Override location of installed extensions
  -endorseddirs <dirs>       Override location of endorsed standards path
  -proc:{none,only}          Control whether annotation processing and/or compilation is done.
  -processor <class1>[,<class2>,<class3>...]Names of the annotation processors to run; bypasses default discovery process
  -processorpath <path>      Specify where to find annotation processors
  -d <directory>             Specify where to place generated class files
  -s <directory>             Specify where to place generated source files
  -implicit:{none,class}     Specify whether or not to generate class files for implicitly referenced files
  -encoding <encoding>       Specify character encoding used by source files
  -source <release>          Provide source compatibility with specified release
  -target <release>          Generate class files for specific VM version
  -version                   Version information
  -help                      Print a synopsis of standard options
  -Akey[=value]              Options to pass to annotation processors
  -X                         Print a synopsis of nonstandard options
  -J<flag>                   Pass <flag> directly to the runtime system
```

Answer (score 4):

[Java doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html) says, (search for cross compilation options)

`By default, classes are compiled against the bootstrap and extension classes of the` `platform that javac shipped with. But javac also supports cross-compiling, where classes` `are compiled against a bootstrap and extension classes of a different Java platform` `implementation. It is important to use -bootclasspath and -extdirs when cross-compiling;` `see Cross-Compilation Example below.`

```
-target version
```

Generate class files that target a specified version of the VM. Class files will run on the specified target and on later versions, but not on earlier versions of the VM. Valid targets are 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5 (also 5), 1.6 (also 6), and 1.7 (also 7).
The default for -target depends on the value of -source:

```
If -source is not specified, the value of -target is 1.7
If -source is 1.2, the value of -target is 1.4
If -source is 1.3, the value of -target is 1.4
If -source is 1.5, the value of -target is 1.7
If -source is 1.6, the value of -target is 1.7
For all other values of -source, the value of -target is the value of -source.
```

So,

```
javac -target 1.6 -source 1.6 yourJavaProgram.java
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below command:

```
javac -target 1.6 -source 1.6 Hello.java
```