# compile java 8 sources to java 7 version

Tags: java, java-8, java-7

I have a java 8 lib that uses the java 8 features and my client need a jar that is compatible with the java 7 version. Is there a solution to compile java 8 sources to java 7 bytecode?

Thank's!

Comment: There is option for this, but it is possible if not using any java 8 specific features. In IntelliJ IDEA IDE, its language level. Check for the same in your IDE or command line option for it.

Comment: **tl;dr** for the dupe: not with built-in tools. A retro-compiler or retroweaver could help, but it's not a 100% solution.

Comment: If the sources don't use any features introduced with Java 8 (e.g. lambdas) it should be doable. If they are using those features you'd have to refactor the sources first.

Comment: Watch this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18162519/set-java-compiler-compliance-level

Comment: Also: for pete's sake: who's still stuck on Java 7? The last free update was 6 years ago!